# How to build framework with xcassets

Tags: ios, swift, xcasset

I tried to build an framework with its own image and it compiles fine. However, when I include my framework in another project, it crashes when loading the image, any idea?

**ImageTest (my framework)**

```
public class ImageTest {
    open func getImage() {
        return #imageLiteral(resourceName: "IMG_0745")
    }
}
```

**My project**

```
import ImageTest
...
...

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let imageView = UIImageView(image: ImageTest.getImage()) // crash !
    imageView.center = view.center
    view.addSubview(imageView)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The image is in ImageTest framework. When you execute this code,  `return #imageLiteral(resourceName: "IMG_0745")`, it looks at the Image.xcassets of ImageTest project and when it does not find the image there, it results in the crash.

Change your code to use bundle param of [init function](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624154-init)

```
open func getImage() {
        return UIImage(named:"IMG_0745", bundle:Bundle(for: self), compatibleWith:nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

In **Swift 5**,

```
UIImage(named: "IMG_0745", in: Bundle(for: xxxYourViewController.self), compatibleWith: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 4 now it is

```
UIImage(named: "IMG_0745", in: Bundle(for:self), compatibleWith: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use such extension per framework, if you lack any classes around:

```
extension UIImage{
    convenience internal init?(namedInBundle name: String, with configuration: UIImage.Configuration? = nil) {
        class ClassForBundleIdentification{}
        let bundle = Bundle(for: ClassForBundleIdentification.self)
        self.init(named: name, in: bundle, with: configuration)
    }
}
```

then you could use it somehow along these lines:

```
public class ImageTest {
    public init(){}
    open func getImage() -> UIImage? {
        UIImage(namedInBundle: "screenshot1")
    }
}
```